# Como limpar um vetor?

Tags: java

Tenho um vetor em Java de tamanho 5 para alocar 5 primeiros números. Tenho de esvaziar quando ele estiver cheio, afim de alocar mais 5 números. E manter esta rotina até todos os números estiverem lidos!

```
int x[] = new int[5];

x[0] = 1
x[1] = 2
x[2] = 3
x[3] = 4
x[4] = 5
```

Comment: Você pode usar um laço for para atribuir um novo valor as posições dos vetores. Por exemplo: for(int i=0;i<x.lenght; x++){ x[i] = 0 }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não posso comentar ainda.
Concordo com a afirmação @Piovezan:

> "Limpar" o vetor nesse caso não é exatamente possível, porque ele está guardando inteiros e não referências que poderiam receber o valor null

Mas creio eu que o código ficaria mais elegante utilizando a classe Arrays do java:

> `Arrays.fill(int[] a, int val)`
>
> Atribui o valor especificado a cada elemento do array de ints.

```
Arrays.fill(x, 0);
```

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int%5B%5D,%20int))

Answer (score 2):

"Limpar" o vetor nesse caso não é exatamente possível, porque ele está guardando inteiros e não referências que poderiam receber o valor `null`.

O máximo que você pode fazer é atribuir um valor neutro (por exemplo zero) a todos os elementos do vetor, caso isso ajude no seu programa, e manter uma variável extra como contador da última posição disponível para se escrever um valor (ou da última posição em que um valor foi escrito, o que quer que seja melhor para o seu programa).

Para atribuir zero a todos os elementos você faz assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = 0;
}
```